# Why istio's mixer logs are working differently for my case?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a DB in namespace `ns-restriction-demo-2` and a nodeJs application that is using that DB from namespace `ns-restriction-demo-1`.
So I was trying to add authorization i.e. DB can only be access by one namespace (ns-restriction-demo-1), but when I enable the mixer logs, I realise that the source attributes are different.

```
{
  "level": "warn",
  "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z",
  "instance": "newlog.instance.ns-restriction-demo-2",
  "destination": "db-demo-2",
  "destinationName": "db-demo-2-868c4bb6c7-f5l7c",
  "destinationNamespace": "ns-restriction-demo-2",
  "destinationPort": 3306,
  "destinationPrinciple": "unkown",
  "latency": "0s",
  "mtls": false,
  "requestHost": "unkown",
  "responseCode": 0,
  "responseSize": 0,
  "source": "calico-node",
  "sourceName": "calico-node-ljzxl",
  "sourceNamespace": "kube-system",
  "sourcePrinicple": "unkown",
  "sourceServiceAccount": "calico-node",
  "sourceservices": "unkown",
  "user": "unknown"
}
```

Configuration I have used

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: newlog
  namespace: ns-restriction-demo-2
spec:
  compiledTemplate: logentry
  params:
    severity: '"warning"'
    variables:
      sourceName: source.name | "unkown"
      sourceNamespace: source.namespace | "unkown"
      sourcePrinicple: source.principal | "unkown"
      sourceServiceAccount: source.serviceAccount | "unkown"
      sourceservices: source.services | "unkown"
      destinationPort: destination.port | 0
      destinationName: destination.name | "unkown"
      destinationNamespace: destination.namespace | "unkown"
      destinationPrinciple: destination.principal | "unkown"
      requestHost: request.host | "unkown"
      source: source.labels["app"] | source.workload.name | "unknown"
      user: source.user | "unknown"
      mtls: connection.mtls | false
      destination: destination.labels["app"] | destination.workload.name | "unknown"
      responseCode: response.code | 0
      responseSize: response.size | 0
      latency: response.duration | "0ms"
    monitored_resource_type: '"UNSPECIFIED"'
---
# Configuration for a stdio handler
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: newloghandler
  namespace: ns-restriction-demo-2
spec:
  compiledAdapter: stdio
  params:
    severity_levels:
      warning: 1 # Params.Level.WARNING
    outputAsJson: true
---
# Rule to send logentry instances to a stdio handler
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: newlogstdio
  namespace: ns-restriction-demo-2
spec:
  match: "true" # match for all requests
  actions:
   - handler: newloghandler
     instances:
     - newlog
---
```

So I have a question for the istio's expert here. 
Why `source` or `sourceName` or `sourceNamespace` is related to calico? why is it not about that nodeJs app that is using this DB?

Please help me understand what have I done wrong or missing something?

**Calico Version**

```
Client Version:    v3.5.8
Git commit:        107e128
Cluster Version:   v3.6.2
Cluster Type:      k8s,bgp,kdd
```

**Other Versions**

- Istio: 1.1.10
- Kubernetes: 1.13.6

Answer (score 0):

Collecting metrics with Mixer for TCP Services is different from the HTTP one.

The access to your database is an example of TCP workload inside Istio Mesh.

Therefore please use a dedicated '[tcpaccesslog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.1/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/mixer/templates/config.yaml)' template instead of 'logentry' one, which includes in attributes mapping a valid protocol configuration:

```
'protocol: context.protocol | "tcp"'
```

This helps Istio to properly derive `source` and `sourceName` attributes.

*Note:*
in case a requests to DB are sent over mTLS enabled TCP connection, you should have available some extra attributes:

- source.workload.name
- source.workload.namespace